How can I add labels for long and short strategy entries?
The script below plots buy and sell at every bullish and bearish condition.  I would like for it to only plot when a long or a short position has been entered. Kindly advise!
if inDateRange
    if bullish
        strategy.entry('long', strategy.long)
        strategy.exit('Stop Long', from_entry='long', stop=longStopLossPrice)

    if Exit_long
        strategy.close('long', comment='exit long)')

    if bearish
        strategy.entry('short', strategy.short)
        strategy.exit('Stop Short', from_entry='short', stop=shortStopLossPrice)

    if Exit_short
        strategy.close('short', comment='exit short)')


// Plot Buy and Sell signals
plot shape(bullish, title="Buy", text="Buy", color=color.green, style=shape.labelup, location=location.abovebar, size=size.small, textcolor=color.white)

plotshape(bearish, title="Sell", text="Sell", color=color.red, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small, textcolor=color.white)


you can use strategy.position_size
something like this:
if inDateRange
    if bullish and strategy.position_size <= 0
        strategy.entry('long', strategy.long)
        strategy.exit('Stop Long', from_entry='long', stop=longStopLossPrice)

    if Exit_long
        strategy.close('long', comment='exit long)')

    if bearish and strategy.position_size >= 0
        strategy.entry('short', strategy.short)
        strategy.exit('Stop Short', from_entry='short', stop=shortStopLossPrice)

    if Exit_short
        strategy.close('short', comment='exit short)')


// Plot Buy and Sell signals
plotshape(bullish and strategy.position_size <= 0, title="Buy", text="Buy", color=color.green, style=shape.labelup, location=location.abovebar, size=size.small, textcolor=color.white)

plotshape(bearish and strategy.position_size >= 0, title="Sell", text="Sell", color=color.red, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small, textcolor=color.white)


This will only work if he doesn't use pyramiding. Better use strategy.position_size > strategy.position_size[1] for longs and strategy.position_size < strategy.position_size[1] for shorts.

That worked a as treat!  Many thanks!                                                             plot_buy = strategy.position_size > strategy.position_size[1]
plot_sell = strategy.position_size < strategy.position_size[1]
